# How do I remove all shared items from Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader, feeds

My shared items feed was private, and I want to make it public, so I decided to remove all it contains.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can "unshare" individual items, but I've not found a way to do it in bulk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there [still isn't a way to bulk unshare items in Google Reader](http://getsatisfaction.com/google_reader/topics/unshare_items_bulk_delete).

The solution offered is to use keyboard shortcuts to make it a bit easier.

While viewing your shared items

1. Press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to unshare the item
2. Press <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd> to move to the next or previous item
3. Return to step 1; Repeat as necessary

I expect you could use something like AutoHotkey to automate this further.

Note: Since the [Google Reader change to utilize Google+](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2011/10/upcoming-changes-to-reader-new-look-new.html), this is no longer possible.

Comment: Really cool. I didnt think in use a macro creator software like AutoHotkey. Thanks!