# How to remove Google Reader shared items page?

Tags: google-reader

I am not using Google Reader anymore and I would like to remove my shared items page found at

`http://www.google.com/reader/shared/<my.gmail.account.username>`

I read this question [How do I remove all shared items from Google Reader?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18131/how-do-i-remove-all-shared-items-from-google-reader)

But, if I find my shared post and click on "Share" I just get the "Share to Google+" dialog and not unshare functionality.

My goal is to remove the page with shared items and any of the following will do:

- unshare one by one
- delete the page all together
- delete the Reader account

Comment: I found where to download your shared items, but not where to remove them from view. Still looking...

Comment: For what it's worth, you may want to follow this [Google Reader Forum thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/reader/shared$20items/reader/LxTcYTIEnKI) and perhaps "star" it. If enough people jump on it Google may get around to fixing it. (There are some other related threads in that forum as well.)

Comment: Since Google Reader is being sunsetted on July 1, this issue will become moot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is not possible at the time of writing.

The best thing you can do is to remove any reference to the link you can find, now that Google Reader moved away from Shared Items (to Google+), I think Google won't link to that page anymore themselves either. So if you remove all references you know of, I doubt if anyone will ever reach that page again.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it very easily. Just go to 
Reader settings >> folders and tags >> click on the 'public' link  against 'your starred items' line. it will make the link to 'Private' and you are done.